# How to write data and headers to csv dynamically?

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

I need to write headers and data into csv. The problem i'm facing is that my data may change order. I want to map my data exactly under the paricular header column. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Ex: My data looks like

```
Min6    ItemNumber  FC1 FC2 Retailer    Brand   Description  Size
630   12549        0     0             Too-Tart  SWEET&SOUR   .7OZ
                   0     0      Ahold  Too-Tart  SWEET&SOUR   .7OZ
                   0     0      Test   Too-Tart  SWEET&SOUR   .7OZ

630   12550        0     0             Too       SWEET&Salt   .60Z
                   0     0      Test   Too       SWEET&SOUR   .7OZ
                   0     0      Ahold  Too       SWEET&SOUR   .23Z
```

and am expecting as

```
   Min6 ItemNumber  FC1 FC2 Retailer    Brand   Description     Size     Ahold-Description Ahold-Brand  Test-Description Test-Brand
   630    12549        0     0             Too-Tart  SWEET&SOUR .7OZ      SWEET&SOUR        Too-Tart     SWEET&SOUR       Too-Tart
   630    12549        0     0             Too-Tart  SWEET&Salt .6OZ      SWEET&SOUR        Too          SWEET&SOUR       Too
```

Here order of the retailer may change and many retailers will be there. For each new retailer new headers will be created. If a retailer is repeated then I want to map his brand and description under his headers exactly which are already created.

```
class CouponsDataPreProcessor < Transformer
  def run(path)
    @records = []
    input_base_name = File.basename(path, '.csv')
    first_row = true
    output_file = File.join('public', "coupons_data_preprocessor_#{input_base_name}_#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')}.csv")
    CSV.open(output_file, 'w') do |csv|
      CSV.foreach(path, {:headers => true}) do |row|
        if first_row
          @headers = row.headers
          first_row = false
        end
        if row['ItemNumber'].present?
          @records << row.fields
        else
          form_retailer_headers_and_fields(row)
        end
      end
      csv << @headers
      @records.each { |record| csv << record }
    end
    output_file
  end

  def form_retailer_headers_and_fields(row)
    retailer = row['Retailer']
    unless @headers.include?("Description-#{retailer}")
      @headers.push("Description-#{retailer}", "Brand-#{retailer}", "SubBrand-#{retailer}", "Size-#{retailer}")
    end
    @records.last.push(row['Description'], row['Brand'], row['SubBrand'], row['Size'])
  end

  def self.about
    'Preprocess coupons data into input line items'
  end
end
```

Here if a retailer is repeated and he is  in different order then i'm not able to map his values exactly under his header columns(ex: Brand-retailername)

How do I create a row object with key as header and value as the value for that header and push it into the output csv file?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise, e.g. showing us the code where you are stuck?

Comment: @leo i have edited my question. Please see that.

Comment: It appears that you are asking someone here to write a program for you. Since that is not the case, please explain what research you have done, and what is missing from your current state of knowledge.

Comment: @dcorking I edited my question with the logic which i have tried.

Comment: Thanks @user3843778 . Please explain what you think is wrong with your code.

Comment: @dcorking, I should create a row object with key as header and value as the value for that header and push it into the output csv file. but I'm not able to get how to do that.

Comment: @user3843778 In that case break it down into a simpler question, with the minimum code and data that you need for that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be several bugs in your code.

1. (line 1) You inherit from `Transformer`, but you don't seem to re-use any methods from Transformer. Consider deleting the inheritance.
2. (line 1) You need `require 'csv'`
3. (line 4) Perhaps you intended to write `File.basename(path << '.csv')`
4. (line 14) You wrote `if row['ItemNumber'].present?` <del>but if that column is empty, then row['ItemNumber'] will be nil, and so the program will abort on MethodMissing.</del>  You probably intended to use the [`present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) method in the activesupport gem, which Stack Overflow users will need to require to test this part of your code

I don't think the CSV library has a tool to detect that the first 2 columns (of row 3 for example) are blank, so I think you need to preprocess with another tool that identifies the columns before using CSV.

You can write a method to identify the column numbers, but I just did it clumsily and manually (please edit my answer with tidier code):

```
COMMA = ','
f = File.open(path)
g = File.open('commas.csv', mode='w')
lines = f.readlines
lines = lines.reject{|ln| ln.length < 61} # reject the short line(s)
lines_with_commas = lines.collect{|ln| ln[0..3] << COMMA << ln[4..17] \
<< COMMA << ln[18..23] << COMMA << ln[24..27] << COMMA << ln[28..38] \
<< COMMA << ln[39..47]<< COMMA << ln[48..60]<< COMMA << ln[61..-1]} 
lines_with_commas.each{ |ln| g.write(ln)}
g.close
```

Then you can import your CSV in one go and search it for retailers.

```
> table = CSV.table('commas.csv')
> table[:retailer_].collect(&:strip).uniq
=> ["", "Ahold", "Test"]
```